# I want to automatically load local video and audio in a phone gap application on the iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, audio, video, cordova

I want to automatically load **local** video and audio without clicking/swiping, etc. on a [PhoneGap](http://www.phonegap.com/) application on the iPad. I'm considering creating an objective-c plugin, would this be the correct way or is there another work around i.e. a plugin, javascript way etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given that a phonegap app is basically a wrapped webapp, I think you may be out of luck, apple requires a user action to play media on the iPad (actually, audio, I don't know either way for video). [Here's a source](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AudioVideo/Conceptual/Using_HTML5_Audio_Video/Device-SpecificConsiderations/Device-SpecificConsiderations.html).

See the user controls or media playback controls section. Even though your data is local, the play action is disabled without an action

Comment: I just want an intro video and maybe a background video, its imperative for the project.  Any suggestions would do?

Comment: This question here has very few answers, other related answers have more. Don't give up.